# Neo4j: Why difference in result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the Cypher query:

```
match(p:Product {StyleNumber : "Z94882A", Color: "Black"})--(stock:Stock {Retailer: "11"}) 
with  sum(stock.Stockcount) as onstock, p
optional match(p)-->(s:Sale {Retailer : "11"}) 
where s.Date = 20170801 
return p.Color,p.Size, onstock as stock, sum(s.Quantity) as sold
```

This gives correctly:

```
Color,Size,Stock,Sold
Black,M,3,0
Black,S,3,1
Black,L,1,1
Black,XL,5,2
```

But if I leave out the Size property in the return statement,and just return:

```
return p.Color, onstock as stock, sum(s.Quantity) as sold
```

This only returns 3 rows  (Size "M" is missing):

```
Black,3,1
Black,1,1
Black,5,2
```

I can't figure out why there is a difference in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the `sum()` aggregation function.

Cypher doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause (like traditional SQL databases), but when you use an aggregation function all non-aggregated fields are implicitly used as grouping fields.

So when you remove `p.Size` from return the first row is grouped with the second row because all values implicitly grouped are equals (`p.Color = 'Black'` and `onstock = 3`). Also, the values of the `Sold` column are used in the `sum()` function (`0 + 1 = 1`), producing the row:

```
Black,3,1
```

Comment: It makes sense... however i'm still a bit puzzled... lets say I wanted to group by color only and get the sum of stock (12) and sold (4)... if I change the return statement to: `return p.Color,sum(onstock) as stock, sum(s.Quantity) as sold`. This returns a sum of 17 as stock (instead of 12) in stock, since XL has 2 sales  (with 1 quantity each, but 5 on stock)..... dont get it :(.....